# Windows 7 - Faster applications/windows switcher, e.g., by typing application's name?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab

I sometimes have many running applications and switching between them with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> becomes very tedious.
I would like to be able to switch between tasks/windows more quickly.
The perfect solution for me would be an application that lets me start typing a window's title and offers a classic auto-complete drop down list to choose from.

Does anybody know of a technique, tool, or lightweight application that offers something similar to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a free application called [Switcher](http://insentient.net/index.html) that boasts many features, one of which is a keyword search integration amongst all open applications.  You can read a review of the application on [Technospot](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/switcher-3d-windows-alt-tab-with-search-integration/).

Comment: It is however, somewhat slow when having an integrated graphics chip like in many laptops. I rarely used it on my laptop with a GMA 950 because of that.

Comment: It's pretty configurable (or at least, it is now), so you can turn off all the fancy animations and stuff, hopefully getting a bit more performance.

Comment: Windows just became a tiny bit more usable, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You might try a little app I wrote, [Switcheroo](https://github.com/jsulak/Switcheroo), which is an incremental-search task-switcher for windows:

[image]

> Switcheroo is for anyone who spends
>   more time using a keyboard than a
>   mouse. Instead of alt-tabbing through
>   a (long) list of open windows,
>   Switcheroo allows you to quickly
>   switch to any window by typing in just
>   a few characters of its title. It's
>   inspired by Emacs's IDO mode buffer
>   switching.

Comment: I've been using Switcheroo for a while and I like it very much. It has become an important part of my computer environment. Thank you for the application, also so far this is the only app I've found that differentiates the applications between Virtual Desktops (I use VirtuaWin) in Windows 10. You should consider updating the screenshot you've used. This old one doesn't do the latest version of the app justice.

Answer (score 3):

The lovely autohotkey scripting language!

```
#NoTrayIcon 
settitlematchmode, RegEx
regex= i)%1%
sleep 100
winactivate, %regex%
ExitApp
Return
```

This takes a command line option of what window you want to switch to (case insensitive regex), so is perfect for somebody already using an application launcher such as [Executor](http://executor.dk), [Launchy](http://launchy.net), so on.

Comment: +1 I used to use a similar script with SlickRun. Now I use it with Promptu, which is sort of an expanded SlickRun in which value lists can be configured, so I can do 'ff' and Promptu will translate it to 'FireFox,' or 'xl' to 'Microsoft Excel', for example.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm not really using it yet, but [Enso](http://humanized.com/enso/) let's you hold caps lock and type what you want to do - including `"go windowname"` and it auto-completes with dropdown.

Comment: I thought Enso's hotkey was capslock? A stellar use of the key, I must admit, and one I nicked using autohotkey :D

Comment: Yes of course, my fingers typed something completely different from what my brain wanted me to ^^ most likely something about auto-completion usually being related to the tab key perhaps? Thx ^^

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem and solved it by writing this alternative task switcher:
http://www.oelgaard.dk/software/torkilstaskswitcher/

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one: [iSwitcher](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33353) is an [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that:

> filters through a list of open windows as you type—with a semi-transparent dialog accessible by simply pressing the Caps Lock key.

[image]

More info at [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5278802/iswitchw-finds-windows-as-you-type)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Task Manager may actually be what you want. 
Invoke it (e.g., by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>), go to the “Applications” tab (if you aren’t there already), select the task you want to go to (click or cursor down or type the first letter of its name), and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click on “Switch To” or double-click on the task name.

Another answer is <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>*n*</kbd>; it will go to the *n*th task on the taskbar.  If you want a certain combination (e.g., <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>) to always go to a certain program, you should pin it to the taskbar.  (If the task has multiple windows, hold <kbd>Win</kbd> while you press <kbd>*n*</kbd> repeatedly, and it will cycle through the windows.)