# How to unhide opened program on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm new on Windows 10 and I want to use Win key like a spotlight on Mac, to find some program and to open it. In case the application is running, but hidden, the Spotlight will unhide it.

How does it work on Windows? I have opened my Intellij Idea and I want to unhide it (get focus on it), but when I will press Win key and will write "IntelliJ Idea", it will do nothing.

*P.S. I downloaded Wox program, it's like a Spotlight on MacOS, but I faced the same problem. Maybe there is some problem in Windows settings?*

Comment: There’s an important conceptional difference: On Windows you can launch an application multiple times. The resultant behavior is up to the application. The “default” behavior in macOS is different: An application bundle can only be launched once (barring `open -n`).

Comment: @DanielB sure, I realized that difference, but is there some way to change it? It's a very handy shortcut and I'm missing it :)
After all, some applications will not appear twice, they will do nothing when I want to open an application in this way.

Comment: there are many alternatives: [Windows 7 - Faster applications/windows switcher, e.g., by typing application's name?](https://superuser.com/q/53573/241386), [Alt-Tab tool to switch to a window by typing its name](https://superuser.com/q/443240/241386). The [Windows powertoys](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerToys) also has that feature